# How to properly handle ProgressDialog using MVVM architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am working on a project where we decided to implement MVVM instead of the traditional MVC. I am looking for the proper way of setting up a ProgressDialog in this case.

Normally you'd have a ProgressDialog on its own async task and during the doInBackground() call you'd fetch any data you'd need to get. However, since we are running MVVM I'm waiting for the VM to return the data to update the view with.

Maybe I just poorly implemented what I originally thought was the correct solution, but I was trying to get the progress dialog async task to wait until the VM returned with the values. Something like the following

```
// Listener that connects VM and View
onPropertyChange() {
    // Update UI
    ...
    flag = true;
}

// Within myAsyncTask
onPreExecute() {
    // Set up ProgressDialog
}

doInBackground() {
    while (!flag) { }
}

onPostExecute() {
    // Dimiss ProgressDialog
}
```

I thought this was a messy solution and thus changed to the following

```
onCreate() {
    // Inject VM and perform super.OnCreate()
    ...

    // Set up ProgressDialog
}

onPropertyChange() {
    // Update UI and dismiss ProgressDialog
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this functionality while having the ProgressDialog on its own AsyncTask instead of on the main thread?

Comment: Just bind the progress bar (or whatev equivalent) to an PercentComplete INPC property on the view model.  INPC updates are marshalled automatically by bindings.  Just don't make 10k updates to that property within a 5 second interval and expect to see anything happen in the UI.

Comment: while (!flag) { }

No.  Not in an  AsyncTask.  AsyncTasks run on the same thread.  By doing this, you hold up any other async tasks from running.  If you actually need this, use a Thread, not an AsyncTask.